# Access variables from different methods

Tags: android, scope

What I need is simple:

If oncreate I have an arraylist created with some items.

But, how can I edit that arraylist(add items,remove) from another function(method)?

Comment: Try to not duplicate your question please! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945272/remove-from-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a object field:

```
public class X extends ThatAndroidAppClassWhatsNameIForgot {
    private List<ItemType> list = new ArrayList<ItemType>();

    public void onCreate() {
        list.add(...);
    }

    private void otherMethod(...) {
        list.remove(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create that array list as a private field of your class. That way it will be visible to oncreate method or any other